# PHP - arrays in session variables

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I have a problem with storing arrays in php session variables.

Let's say I have a session variable, and I assign to it array of objects.

```
$_SESSION['xxx'] = [new Obj(data[0], data[1]), new Obj(data[0], data[1])];
```

When I print the contents of $_SESSION['xxx'] after that, I get correct results. But when I follow a link to other page and try to read content of $_SESSION['xxx'] there, I get sth like that:

```
array('0'=>array('0'=> NULL, '1'=> NULL), '1'=>array('0'=> NULL, '1'=> NULL) )
```

Do you have an idea what can be a reason of that? For sure it is the same session.

Regards
Michal

Update

code of class:

```
class Bsk_pps {
public $id;         //bsk_id
public $name;       //bsk_name
public $code;       //bsk_code
public $type;
public $count;      //count of PROPERTIES elements assigned to this BUSINESS KEY



public function __construct($id, $name, $code, $type, $count) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->code = $code;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->count = $count;
}
}
```

Comment: You're 110% sure you're not assigning it a new dummy value somewhere on the way?

Comment: what's this object? Can it be serialized properly?

Comment: Are the classes available / defined when you get the object from the session?

Comment: what's the Obj class?  Do you mean stdClass or is this some other class of your own devising?  If it's the latter, can it be safely serialised and has it been loaded before you attempt to start the session?

Comment: Drop the code of "Obj" class

Comment: @jeroen: you mean, if class is inclided in the second site? Yes, it is icluded.